# VSCode Rest Client Extension - Get value from property responser json complex object

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Using Visual Studio Code and Rest Client Extension:
I am calling an endpoint that returns a JSON object. I'm trying to get the "AccessToken" property of that object, but it doesn't return a value.
What could be doing wrong?

This is the .rest file

```
###LOGIN
# @nane loginrequest
POST https://someurl
content-type: application/json

{ "username":"someuser",    "password":"somepassword",  "refresh_token": null }

// THE RESPONSE IS:
//// {
//     "Error": false,
//     "Success": true,
//     "Message": "Login ok.",
//     "Data": {
//       "IdToken": "xxxxx",
//       "RefreshToken": "yyyyy",
//       "AccessToken": "zzzzz",
//       "ExpiresIn": 21600
//     },
//     "ResultCode": 200
//   }

### VARIABLE RESPONSE TO FILL TOKEN
@authtoken= {{loginrequest.response.body.$.Data.AccessToken}

### VCloud Stores API Gateway . GetOrdersIds
GET https://someurl  HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: {{authtoken}}
```

Comment: `@authtoken= {{loginrequest.response.body.$.Data.AccessToken}` ← the first `{` is never closed.  Could that be it?

Comment: I feel like a fool...it was that and that the @nane was also misspelled. 

thanks! i lost 3 hours....

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a fool...it was a missing "}" at end of line and that the @nane was also misspelled.

thanks to @timothy G.